# Chrome tabs suddenly become black

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, google-chrome

I am using

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Chrome: Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

When I use chrome and after some time it becomes like this

[image]

The same issue was occurring with me in Ubuntu 16.04 as well. That's why I install the ubuntu 18.04. But it is still occurring. Ths time I did not install any extension even then it is happening. I try to search it's solution but until now did not find any solution. Can you please help me to solve it?

Thank You!

Comment: In Settings, Advanced, do you have hardware acceleration on or off? If it's on, try turning it off.